# Add columns from different data frames and stack on two indicators

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, melt

We’d like to merge some columns from a data frame with the matching columns from various different data frames. Our main data frame *predict* looks as follows:

```
>predict
 x1    x2    x3
 1     1     1
 0     1     0
 1     1     0
 1     1     0
 0     0     1
```

(There may be more columns depending on the quantity of prediction runs)

Our goal is to merge this data frame with the y-columns from three different *test* data frames (*df_1* *df_2* and *df_3*) which all have the same structure. The needed columns are accessed through `df_1$y[test]` ([test] is a logical vector which identifies the 5 values which match our x-values) and have the same structure as the x-columns from *predict*.

The desired output would look like this:

```
>predict_test
 x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3 
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     1     0     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     1     0
 1     1     0     1     1     1
 0     0     1     0     0     1
```

In the next step we need to stack the x- and the y- columns into one column in order to do evaluations. It is important to stack them in the correct order, i.e. x2 under x1 and x3 under x2. The y-columns respectively.

```
>predict_test_stack
 x_all y_all
 1     1
 0     0
 1     0
 1     1
 0     0
 1     1
 1     0
 1     1
 1     1
 0     0
 1     1
 0     0
 0     0
 0     1
 1     1
```

This probably works with `melt`, but we don't know how to apply it while indicating two different id variables.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "x1    x2    x3
1     1     1
0     1     0
1     1     0
1     1     0
0     0     1",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "y1    y2    y3
1     1     1
0     0     0
0     1     0
1     1     1
0     0     1",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE)
```

**solution**

we concatenate the data.frames, then unlist the `data.frame`, keeping the correct number of columns. Finally we set the names by going into the data.frames to find the pattern.

```
list1 <- list(df1,df2)
side_by_side <- data.frame(list1)
#   x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
# 1  1  1  1  1  1  1
# 2  0  1  0  0  0  0
# 3  1  1  0  0  1  0
# 4  1  1  0  1  1  1
# 5  0  0  1  0  0  1

output <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(side_by_side),ncol = length(list1)))
names(output) <- sapply(list1,function(x){sub("[[:digit:]]","",names(x)[1])})
#     x  y
# 1   1  1
# 2   0  0
# 3   1  0
# 4   1  1
# 5   0  0
# 6   1  1
# 7   1  0
# 8   1  1
# 9   1  1
# 10  0  0
# 11  1  1
# 12  0  0
# 13  0  0
# 14  0  1
# 15  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks @Moody_mudskipper. I learned some useful basic stuff from that. One more question: what does the `sub` in the sapply command exactly do?

Comment: It replaces any digit by the empty string in the first column name of the relevant `data.frame`. I had made a copy paste mistake and the printed names of the output were wrong, I replaced them with x and y now :).

Comment: One more thing I just noticed is that creating the *output* using `unlist` transforms my original x values from (0,1) into (1,2).
Any suggestion?

Comment: make sure to use the parameter `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` each time you define a `data.frame`, convert to a  `data.frame`, or read an external files (`read.csv` etc)

Comment: the quick fix is to use `unlist(as.numeric(as.character(...)))` but try to solve it upstream

Comment: The problem occurs just in the last step; after stacking the columns. `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` unfortunately doesn't help much. The `unlist(as.numeric(as.character(...)))` produces a warning message, saying *NAs introduced by coercion*. Anyway, I just retranform the values back to 0&1. Suggestions for a more elegant solutions are welcome :)